# Can I programmatically set this modeless dialog to be hidden so it is not even seen momentarily?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cdialog

In my application I have two editors and each editor is displayed in a **modal** dialog.

I am working on some test code to use one editor *from within* the other editor, to obtain data. This second editor is being loaded as a **modeless** dialog:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::EditDutyAssignments()
{
    auto pDlgReport = std::make_unique<CCreateReportDlg>();
    if (pDlgReport != nullptr && m_pEntry != nullptr)
    {
        pDlgReport->SetFileToOpen(L"d:\\test.srr", L"test.srr");
        pDlgReport->Create(IDD_DIALOG_CREATE, this);
        pDlgReport->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

        // Do stuff

        pDlgReport->DestroyWindow();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the modeless dialog flashes, Can I configure it programmatically to not be visible in this context?

---

I tried:

```
DWORD dwStyle = ::GetWindowLong(pDlgReport->GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE);
dwStyle &= ~WS_VISIBLE; //remove WS_VISIBLE
::SetWindowLong(pDlgReport->GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE, dwStyle);

pDlgReport->Create(IDD_DIALOG_CREATE, this);
pDlgReport->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
```

And it did not work. I think this is because the `Create` method is loading the actual dialog resource and thus overriding my style changes.

Comment: What is it in the Windows resource? Is the WS_VISIBLE flag set in the resource? If it is, remove the flag from the resource?

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Can’t do that because I also use it as a visible modal editor. I used the linked answer. I set a bool flag and added the winposchangi g event handler.